# Getting tabId -1 in onBeforeRequest in Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In my Chrome extension I listen to `onBeforeRequest` and there is a mystery with one domain: https://www.vinyl-digital.com/

The problem: `tabId === -1` instead of a valid tab id in the listener. Also `type === xmlhttprequest` appears, although that is a not an XHR request definitely:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener()

frameId: -1
initiator: "https://www.vinyl-digital.com"
method: "GET"
parentFrameId: -1
requestId: "586533"
tabId: -1
timeStamp: 1554487869165.11
type: "xmlhttprequest"
url: "https://www.vinyl-digital.com/"
```

I'd like to know a possible cause for that -1 and how to start getting valid IDs.

To reproduce it, I created a fresh Chrome profile, added my extension, in a new tab typed in the URL, press Enter. The first and only time the `tabId` is a valid (!) number. All other times I'm getting -1 and "xmlhttprequest".

Chrome 73.0.3683.86 (Official Build) (64-bit) Win 7

Comment: On your first visit the site install a service worker, which handles the subsequent requests and emits XHRs from its context that's not a tab so the id is -1 as per webRequest documentation.

Comment: @wOxxOm Your help is valuable as always, thanks! I will accept your answer once you add it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your first visit the site install a service worker (you can see it in devtools -> Application tab), which handles the subsequent requests and emits XHRs from its context that's not a tab so the id is `-1` as per [webRequest documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest):

> `tabId`: The ID of the tab in which the request takes place.
>     **Set to -1 if the request isn't related to a tab.**

Comment: Is it possible to find out from which site/tab a service worker was started? Without knowing the origin of the request it's hardly possible to apply many required algorithms in onBeforeRequest.